# Access original value of property on DS.Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to access original property value on models in Ember-data? Consider an html form with H1 title binding to model property. Now when property changed, the header also get changed. It's weird. I would like to bind original value and get bindings updated only after successful commit.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to bind to another property in your `ObjectController` and then only push these changes to the model when you want it to.